# How can I go to those systems without hyperspace links?

Tags: endless-sky

I was just looking in my map, and I find there are some worlds which doesn't have hyperspace links to them. I don't know how to get to those systems. Are they just decorations, or is it some kind of unfinished code? If neither, how do I get there?

Comment: Apparently it's possible to get a special hyperdrive to go to nearby systems in the endgame

Comment: Yes, there is. See my answer below. This might help those new and curious players asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the two. They are real, and they are functioning. You need to replace or add alongside your Hyperdrive a Jump Drive which will enable you to reach to those systems.

### To get the Jump Drive

To get that device, you would need to either **finish the main story** (the Free Worlds campaign or in the future, also the Navy campaign), or **wait for some alien ships in Polaris and plunder their Jump Drive**. It is easier to finish the main story because you would be given a free Jump Drive (only if you chose to war against the Syndicate). But if you choose the latter, you will need a large fleet to defeat those alien ships, because of its high shield strength and hull repair. Not to mention their high-powered weapons.

### What to do now?

Once you have a Jump Drive, you can jump to any system you want. Remember though that a Jump Drive uses **two times the fuel** a Hyperdrive uses, so you will need to refuel more often. Lastly, **always have a ramscoop with you**, a lot of those systems are either uninhabited or only have planets/moons/stations that refuel but doesn't let you land (and there are some you can't bribe because of the language). You wouldn't want to get stranded because of curiousity, right?

But if you don't care about being spoiled, okay then.

### SPOILER WARNING!

To get your free Jump Drive, you would have to rescue the Syndicate defector. Ignore Freya's warning. Eventually your choice will be correct (as you hoped), as the Navy's Questioner finds that the defector is telling the truth. After some arresting stuff (especially the nukes, will take you a lot of reloads to get through that), you will get a free Jump Drive from the Syndicate (yes, from the Syndicate, you will see the terrorist are not really the Syndicate, but an extremist faction in them).

If you chose not to rescue the defector (because you like fights and nukes), then you will need to plunder a Jump Drive from the Pug in the space in which the hyperspace links are cut off. I recommend doing this before leaving Pug space so that the Pug in Rasalhague will be friendly (don't know why).

If you chose not to finish the story at all, then you will need to wait some Korath Raiders in Polaris. They are very strong, so a large fleet is needed. If you run away, Korath Chasers will chase you, and they are probably faster than you. It may be better to finish them first.

Comment: Headings pls. A wall of text isn't very helpful to anyone really

Comment: Done. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yeah, much better now